Couldn't create partition in ubuntu 22.04LTS
Can I create a new partition from an existing EC2 EBS root volume?, I'm try to create a partition using fdisk command but "target is too busy" stdout on screen

Welcome to AskUbuntu. If the volume is currently mounted, then a partition cannot be added or modified.
